# h. file not found while adding Firebase to Flutter app

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods

I'm trying to add Firebase support to my Flutter app but I'm getting an issue where I searched many times on the internet + stack overflow but haven't got any solutions at all.

Some say that this is some kind of Swift issue but I'm not sure.

Below is my log I got from Android Studio while trying to build my app.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           14,4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/ardacebi/Desktop/histic/histic/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'firebase_admob/FirebaseAdMobPlugin.h' file not found
    #import <firebase_admob/FirebaseAdMobPlugin.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XR.
```

This happened after I added Firebase FlutterFire Plugins (all of them as I need them) reading this guide:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Do you guys have any solutions? Thanks.

### Some files of mine that may help

#### Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

#### pubspec.yaml

```
name: histic
description: Scientific discussion platform.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.3.0
  firebase_admob: ^0.8.0
  firebase_analytics: ^0.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.0+1
  firebase_database: ^2.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^3.0.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.2.0
  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.3.0
  firebase_performance: ^0.1.0
  firebase_remote_config: ^0.1.0
  firebase_storage: ^2.0.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

#### AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
        ) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

Comment: how about check this link?? [stackoverflow.com/a/55962172/8912043](http://stackoverflow.com/a/55962172/8912043) I hope to U solve it

Answer (score 3):

this case caused by Pod broken installation.
So first you need a fresh binary installation, run below command to clear the project cache in the project directory:

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
```

then install again, and wait until the end:

```
pod install
```

Comment: This works with me. My error was: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
    #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
and I had this error after I updated my Xcode to 12.3

Answer (score 1):

For me, I deleted the ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework folder and install pods pod install again then it worked.